# Visual Studio 2015 C2011 'Class' type redefinition

Tags: c++, class

im currently working on a small console app, i read from some files, and i have made a simple animated loading bar thread to show the progress of file reading (sometimes the file are really huge)

i have read on the microsoft documentation and on the forum and that error seems to suggest that i defined the class multiple time.

but i did include all the header blocks to prevent this from happenning, any of you see my mistake, probly obvious, i havent done c++ in years.

here is the code

fileReader.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FILEREADER_H // must be unique name in the project
#define FILEREADER_H

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class fileReader {

private:

public:
    vector<string> readTextFile(string path);
    unsigned int getSize();
    unsigned int getLoadedBytes();
};
#endif      // FILEREADER_H
#pragma once
```

fileReader.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#include "numbers.h"
#include "loadingBar.h"


using namespace std;

class fileReader {
private:

public :
    vector<string> list;
    int i;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int loadedBytes;
    string line;
    std::thread* barThread;

    vector<string> fileReader::readTextFile(string path) {

        ifstream file(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

        i = 0;
        size = 0;
        loadedBytes = 0;

        ifstream file(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

        if (file.is_open()) {
            size = file.tellg();
            cout << "\t" << path << " (" << formatNumbers(size) << " bytes)" << endl;
            file.clear();
            file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

            barThread = new std::thread(&loadingBar::run, *this);

            while (file >> line) {
                list.push_back(line);
                loadedBytes += strlen(line.c_str());
                i++;
            }

        }
        else {
            cout << "Error reading : \"" << path << "\"" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        file.close();
        return list;
    }

    unsigned int fileReader::getSize() { return size; }
    unsigned int fileReader::getLoadedBytes() { return loadedBytes; }

};
```

loadingBar.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LOADINGBAR_H
#define LOADINGBAR_H

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include "numbers.h"
#include "fileReader.h"

using namespace std;

class loadingBar {
public:
    void notififyFinish();
    void notifyError();
    void notifiError(string);
    void drawloadingBar();
    void drawPathBar();
    void drawBytesBar();
    void setLoadedUnits(int);
    void setTotalUnits(int);
    void run(fileReader*);

};

#endif // NUMBERS_H
```

loadingBar.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

#include "numbers.h"
#include "fileReader.h"

using namespace std;

class loadingBar {

private:

public:

    double totalUnits = 1;
    double loadedUnits = 0;
    char loadedChar = '/';
    char emptyChar = ' ';
    int barLength = 50;
    double percent;
    int nbChar;

    void notiftyFinish() {
        cout << " Ok" << endl;
        //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    void notifiyError() {
        cout << " Error !" << endl;
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void notifiyError(string errMess) {
        cout << " Error !" << endl << "\t" << errMess;
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void drawLoadingBar() {
        cout << fixed;

        cout << "\rLoading [";

        for (int i = 0; i < nbChar; i++)
            cout << loadedChar;

        for (int i = nbChar; i < barLength - 1; i++)
            cout << emptyChar;

        cout << "] " << setprecision(0) << percent << "%";
    }

    void drawPathBar(string path) {
        cout << fixed;

        cout << "\rLoading [ ";

        cout << path;

        cout << " ] " << setprecision(0) << percent << "%";
    }

    void drawBytesBar() {
        cout << fixed;

        cout << "\rLoading [ ";

        cout << formatNumbers(loadedUnits) << " / " << formatNumbers(totalUnits);

        cout << " ] " << setprecision(0) << percent << "%";
    }

    void setLoadedUnits(int newValue) {
        if (newValue > 0)
            loadedUnits = newValue;
    }

    void setTotalUnits(int value) {
        if (value > 0)
            totalUnits = value;
    }

    void run(fileReader *f) {
        setTotalUnits(f->getSize());
        setLoadedUnits(f->getLoadedBytes());

        while (loadedUnits <= totalUnits) {
            setLoadedUnits(f->getLoadedBytes());
            percent = ((double)(loadedUnits / totalUnits) * 100);
            nbChar = (int)(percent / (int)(100 / barLength));

            drawLoadingBar();

            //setLoadedUnits((int)loadedUnits + 10);

            if (loadedUnits >= totalUnits) notiftyFinish();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You do redeclare the class in your implementation file? What's unclear about that error message actually? Also stop to use `using namespace std;`, particularly in header files. I'm pretty sure that is a duplicate question finally, just to lazy to search right now (that's your responsibility anywas at all.)

Comment: You're declaring the classes in bot h header and CPP. That's why you get the error. Check how the implementation is done in the CPP files and you'll get rid of it. No `class...` there needed and all member variables to the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .cpp files redefine your classes. You've already defined them in the respective .h files. All you need to include in your .cpp files is the implementations. They should look more like this:

**fileReader.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#include "numbers.h"
#include "loadingBar.h"

vector<string> fileReader::readTextFile(string path) {

    ifstream file(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    i = 0;
    size = 0;
    loadedBytes = 0;

    ifstream file(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        size = file.tellg();
        cout << "\t" << path << " (" << formatNumbers(size) << " bytes)" << endl;
        file.clear();
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        barThread = new std::thread(&loadingBar::run, *this);

        while (file >> line) {
            list.push_back(line);
            loadedBytes += strlen(line.c_str());
            i++;
        }

    }
    else {
        cout << "Error reading : \"" << path << "\"" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    file.close();
    return list;
}

unsigned int fileReader::getSize() { return size; }
unsigned int fileReader::getLoadedBytes() { return loadedBytes; }
```

Similarly for **loadingBar.cpp**.